# Highlight occurrences on click

Tags: emacs

How to automatically highlight all occurrences of a word, when you click on it?

I don't use mouse often, but would like my editor to be as interactive as it could be.

*Like this, but more intelligent:*

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this snippet for selecting the current word: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MarkCommands#toc5

I had a go at using this to construct something like what you're asking for.  Probably not exactly what you want, but hopefully a starting point.

```
(defun click-select-word (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (hi-lock-mode 0)
  (let ((phrase (concat "\\b" (regexp-quote (thing-at-point 'symbol)) "\\b")))
    (highlight-regexp phrase)))

(global-set-key [mouse-1] 'click-select-word)
```

Comment: This one doesn't use regular expressions, which is clearer to read and utilises `bounds-of-thing-at-point`, so you can feed it a word, a symbol or whatever. This is a win all over.

Comment: i tried in emacs, this script does not work, at least the parenthesis is not matched. i added a right parenthesis after ...phrase)), still not working, please confirm, thx

Comment: Yes, that paren was missing - thanks I've re-edited.  I've just tested and it is still working for me.  Mind elaborating on the failure?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `idle-highlight-mode` to get a similar behavior. This highlights all the occurences of the word at point without the need to click.

This mode can be installed from `package.el`.

Comment: Alas, by timer is *a bit* too much interactive.

Comment: What do you mean by toom much interactive?

Comment: I mean, it wastes CPU when you don't need it and you *also* have to wait, when you actually need it.

Comment: By setting the timer to 0 I do not wait for it and I cannot see a visible CPU impact. You could probably use the function `idle-highlight-word-at-point` defined in `idle-highlight-mode.el` to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, it's very ease to [highlight JavaScript **variables in scope** using Tern](https://github.com/ternjs/tern/blob/master/emacs/tern.el#L372).

[image: gif]

You can bind it to mouse click:

```
(autoload 'tern-mode "tern" nil t)
(tern-mode t)
(local-set-key [mouse-1] 'tern-highlight-refs)
```